# POST data getting lost: Content Length = 0

Tags: forms, post, content-length

I've been trying to find a solution for ages with no success. On our app, customers submit a form and on the next page we process it. Sometimes though the data never arrives. This seems to happen for just a few of our customers. Seems to happen with IE7 and using a proxy.

Here's some headers, note the HTTP_VIA:

```
X-REWRITE-URL: /process.asp?r=699743 
APPL_MD_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/31555/ROOT
APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH: C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\
AUTH_PASSWORD: 
AUTH_TYPE: 
AUTH_USER: 
CERT_COOKIE: 
CERT_FLAGS: 
CERT_ISSUER: 
CERT_KEYSIZE: 
CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE: 
CERT_SERIALNUMBER: 
CERT_SERVER_ISSUER: 
CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT: 
CERT_SUBJECT: 
CONTENT_LENGTH: 0
CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
HTTPS: off
HTTPS_KEYSIZE: 
HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE: 
HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER: 
HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT: 
INSTANCE_ID: 31555
INSTANCE_META_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/31555
LOCAL_ADDR: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
LOGON_USER: 
PATH_INFO: /process.asp
PATH_TRANSLATED: C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\process.asp
QUERY_STRING: r=699743
REMOTE_ADDR: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
REMOTE_HOST: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
REMOTE_USER: 
REQUEST_METHOD: POST
SCRIPT_NAME: /process.asp
SERVER_NAME: www.mysite.com
SERVER_PORT: 80
SERVER_PORT_SECURE: 0
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
URL: /process.asp
HTTP_CONNECTION: Keep-Alive
HTTP_PRAGMA: no-cache
HTTP_VIA: 1.1 WEBCACHE-2
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH: 0
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP_ACCEPT: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-gb
HTTP_COOKIE: ASPSESSIONIDQCKSDCTS=FENMPCMDCHEOENGOJPGDGPLN;
HTTP_HOST: www.mysite.com
HTTP_REFERER: http://www.mysite.com/theform.asp
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)
HTTP_UA_CPU: x86
HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL: /process.asp?r=699743
```

Comment: How do I fix it? POST data is getting lost, there should be post data and there isn't. I'm just doing Request.Form but there is nothing in the Request.Form object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been having the same problem.

POST requests from IE7/IE8 that go through ISA proxy are sometimes (maybe one time in 50) missing the POST data, and have a content-length of 0.

This is a known issue with ISA - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942638 which provides a fix.

Comment: That link doesn't help us since we don't use NTLM authentication. Thanks though

Comment: Do you mean your webserver doesn't use NTLM authentication? That doesn't mean NTLM authentication isn't being done between the user's browser and an ISA proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem today and all answers on topic end up with Windows NTLM answer. I had Linux and Chrome, POST always got `CONTENT_LENGTH=0` and I was debugging in C++ code to understand what I did wrong. As I finally found out, I was missing `name` attribute in `<input ..../>` fields. Without names nothing was submitted. Hope it helps someone who looks for similar issue.